# Aligning items vertically and hiding elements in Bootstrap 5 doesn't work together?

Tags: alignment, display, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and I'm vertically center aligning this div and also hiding this section when the screen size is md and smaller. But for some reason it vertically center aligns only if I don't have the " d-none d-md-block". Once I add the " d-none d-md-block" in, it doesn't center vertically anymore. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

````
<div
      class="
        d-flex
        col-md-5
        align-items-center
        justify-content-evenly
        px-5
        bg-secondary
        d-none d-md-block
      "
    > ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d-flex` sets `display: flex` in CSS
`d-md-block` sets `display: block` in CSS .. you're overriding the "flex".

Change your `d-md-block` to `d-md-flex`.  *(Also delete `d-flex` as you don't need it.)*